# Can't Run py2app on Mac big sur : Launch error See the py2app website for debugging launch issues

Tags: python, macos, py2app

So im just trying to run a filemanager code and i want it to run as an application.

```
from setuptools import setup
APP = ['FileManager.py']
OPTIONS = {
    'argv_emulation':True,

}

setup(
    app = APP,
    options = {'py2app':OPTIONS},
    setup_requires = ['py2app']
)
```

But i am running into this error :

```
Launch error
See the py2app website for debugging launch issues
```

I am running this app on the same mac that i used to write the script. I tried to check the given website (https://py2app.readthedocs.io/en/latest/debugging.html#debugging-application-building) but i Don't understand as i am not very experienced in python and py2app.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting 'argv_emulation' to False

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error. The command provided in the website where it says "launch the application as follows", is equivalent to the following:

1. Right click on the application package created by py2app in "dist" folder, in your case it should be named *FileManager*.
2. Click on "Show Package Contents".
3. Go to contents -> MacOS. You should see a Unix executable named *FileManager*. Double click to see if it could run.

In my case I had no problem running the executable in step 3. Then my workaround is right click on the executable and select "Make Alias". Simply drag the alias to Desktop or any other places you want. Boom. You could double click and run your app.

PS: I really appreciate it if the py2app team could fix this problem.